# How does Test Automation fit in the Continuous Delivery pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, skillset, jenkins-pipeline, devops, cicd

I work with Selenium, Java, Cucumber etc...and create Automation frameworks. My team is now using a CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins. How can i contribute to the delivery pipeline with Automation?

What tools do i need to learn?

Comment: Welcome to the community @jeff! 
Recommendation : Always ask question with background of whats error or problem you are facing with solutions you have tried and any observation if any. Avoid opinion based questions to seek great and quick help from community members

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have added my thoughts and ans below. This is quite general thoughts for your general question. I would be pleased if you have any specific query or question in coming future

Answer (score -1):

CD Pipeline :

- Groovy script is famous for pipelining and integration with CI/CD
- If you can brush up or learn Groovy as language will definitely level up for you in order to contribute for delivery pipeline
- For actual use of automation, its a open grass land. You can automate website, mobile apps, APIs and each one is having multiple tools available in the market today
- For automation you might need a backing from any of the language like Java, Python, C# or Ruby etc